# Turning off Virtualization for Tabcontrol without itemsource - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, avalondock, oxyplot

I have a bug with Tabcontrols and Oxyplot. The Structure of my xaml is like this: I have an AvalonDock document and inside I have 3 harcoded tabs for each document. One of those tabs has another tabcontrol with an Oxyplot View inside each tab. Problem is when I open two (sometimes three) Avalondock Documents, I get the following exception:

```
This PlotModel is already in use by some other PlotView control.
```

I guess it is because the tabcontrol is virtualizing the tabs, and the plot model is being used several times for different views. How can I prevent it?

Problem is very similar to this one,

http://discussion.oxyplot.org/topic/506228-error-this-plotmodel-is-already-in-use-by-some-other-plotview-control/

but I don't think it doesn't have solution yet. I tried the virtualization-off solution given here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/460989/WPF-TabControl-Turning-Off-Tab-Virtualization

and worked properly, but that was for tabs from a template and Not from hardcoded tabs.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Regards.

Saul Hidalgo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to remove view from PlotModel

```
private PlotVm vm = new PlotVm();
    private void LayoutRoot_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        var window = new PlotWindow();
        ((IPlotModel)vm.Model)?.AttachPlotView(null);
        window.DataContext = vm;

        Debug.WriteLine(vm.Model.PlotView);
        window.ShowDialog();
        Debug.WriteLine(vm.Model.PlotView);
    }
```